# Add textbox dynamically and post it to controller mvc

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am new to mvc.for my application I have create collection in view. Lets say I have to display name and address first time. If user clicks copy it should clone the div of name and address. Even I clone it using Jquery it dosent textboxes. And I have to submit all the data back to controller.But it posting only first entry

```
I have created viewmodel and loop in view to display those in view. As index is 0 initially it is not displaying those text box. 

    public class Person
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
    }
    public class PersonVM
    {
        public PersonVM()
        {
            Persons = new List<Person>();
        }
        public IList<Person> Persons { get; set; }
    }




    @model MvcApplication5.Models.PersonVM
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<script src="~/Script/JavaScript.js"></script>
<div class="example-1">

    @using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Person", FormMethod.Post, new { @id = "formpost", @class = "main-form" } ))
    {

        <div class="example-2">

            @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Persons.Count(); i++)
            {
                <p>Example one</p>
                <p>Example two</p>

                @Html.TextBoxFor(p => p.Persons[i].Name, null, new { @class = "form-control" })

                @Html.TextBoxFor(p => p.Persons[i].Address, null, new { @class = "form-control" })

            }

            <button type="button" class="btn-copy">Copy</button>

        </div>
        <input type="submit" id="submit" name="Submit" />

    }


</div>

<script>
    $(function () {
        $(".btn-copy").on('click', function () {
            var ele = $(this).closest('.example-2').clone(true);
            console.log(ele.find('input'));
            //var currentIndex = $(ele).split("[")[1][0];
            //var newIndex = Number(currentIndex) + 1;
            ele.find('input').each(function () {
                console.log($(ele));
                this.id = this.id.replace('0', '[' + 2 + ']');
                this.name = this.name.replace('[0]', '[' + 2 + ']');
                //$(ele).attr("name", $(ele).attr("name").replace(currentIndex, newIndex));
            });
            $(this).closest('.example-2').after(ele);
        });
        $(".main-form").on("submit", function () {
            //You might need to replace the selector here with something better and
            //repeat this for the name as well, or modify it to work with the whole div.
            //$.each($(".example-2"), function (index, inputContainer) {
            //    $.each($(inputContainer).children("div").children("input"), function (inputIndex, input) {
            //        var currentIndex = $(input).attr("name").split("[")[1][0];
            //        $(input).attr("name", $(input).attr("name").replace(currentIndex, index));
            //    });
            //});
            console.log($('.example-2').val);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit:- I have looked at the code more carefully, and recreated it again. I have made some minor changes but here is how it looks now.

```
//My Controller action methods
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        var emptyModel = new PersonVM() {
            Persons = new List<Person>()
        };
        emptyModel.Persons.Add(new Person());
        return View(emptyModel);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Index(PersonVM people)
    {
        return View(people);
    }
```

I did not make any change to the view. But I have included it all here

```
@model PersonVM

<div class="example-1">

    @using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Person", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "main-form"}))
    {


        <div class="example-2">


            <div>

                @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Persons.Count(); i++)
                {
                    <p>Example one</p>
                    <p>Example two</p>

                    @Html.TextBoxFor(p => p.Persons[i].Name, null, new { @class = "form-control" })

                    @Html.TextBoxFor(p => p.Persons[i].Address, null, new { @class = "form-control" })

                }

                <button type="button" class="btn-copy">Copy</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <input type="submit" name="Submit" />


    }


</div>
<script>
    $(function () {
        $(".btn-copy").on('click', function () {
            var ele = $(this).closest('.example-2').clone(true);
            $(this).closest('.example-2').after(ele);
        });
        $(".main-form").on("submit", function () {
            //You might need to replace the selector here with something better and
            //repeat this for the name as well, or modify it to work with the whole div.
            $.each($(".example-2"), function (index, inputContainer) {
                $.each($(inputContainer).children("div").children("input"), function (inputIndex, input) {
                    var currentIndex = $(input).attr("name").split("[")[1][0];
                    $(input).attr("name", $(input).attr("name").replace(currentIndex, index));
                });
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Here is my submitted form.
[image]

Here is the debug ouput.
[image]

Hope this solves your problem. One gotcha would be to have to clear the value of the Person name and field every time you clone but that can be easily achieved.

You are seeing this because all the textboxes that are being submitted have the same index, and every new value just overrides the existing value when model binding occurs. You have two ways of solving this. Either in your click listener assign new indices, or wait till the user submits the form. Here are the code samples.

Example - 1: Update index after before adding new textbox.

```
<script>
    //This assumes sequential indices.
    $(function () {
        $(".btn-copy").on('click', function () {
            var ele = $(this).closest('.example-2').clone(true);
            var currentIndex = $(ele).split("[")[1][0];
            var newIndex = Number(currentIndex) + 1;
            $(ele).attr("name", $(ele).attr("name").replace(currentIndex, newIndex);
            $(this).closest('.example-2').after(ele);
        })
    });
</script>
```

Example - 2: Continue the current method and apply indexes on submit.

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $(".btn-copy").on('click', function () {
            var ele = $(this).closest('.example-2').clone(true);
            $(this).closest('.example-2').after(ele);
        });
        $("{selector for form}").on("submit", function() {
            //You might need to replace the selector here with something better and 
            //repeat this for the name as well, or modify it to work with the whole div.
            $.each("input[name='Persons[i].Address']", function(index, input){
                var currentIndex = $(input).split("[")[1][0];
                var newIndex = Number(currentIndex) + 1;
                $(input).attr("name", $(input).attr("name").replace(currentIndex, newIndex);                
            });
        });
    })


</script>
```

Comment: I am not able to render textbox on first time form gets load. As index is 0 at that time. Anyway to overcome this?

Comment: Yes, That way you can take the second approach and just provide a unique selector. The main question is, if the initial list is empty how are you going to use clone?

Comment: Yes primary requirement.

Comment: We had to deal with a similar situation. In your controller, you can do a null check to see if the the list is empty or not and if it is, then just instantiate it and add an empty person object to it. ```if(viewModelInstance.Persons == null){viewModelInstance.Persons = new List<Person>().Add(new Person())}```

Comment: @AbhishekDeshmukh I have update the post with examples and code. Hope this solves your problem.

Comment: Now I am able to get those boxes and will figure out how to proceed. You made my task easy!!! Thanks a lot Buddy!!!!

Comment: I have posted updated view. When I am posting it only first data is going. I have hardcoded for second as of now.

Comment: You need to uncomment the submit event listener, see what that is doing is going through the dom tree and assigning indices. That is what's actually going to submit those multiple values.

Comment: It posting both element from Dom. On Form collection I am getting all the value. If it doesn't work I have to go for formcollection :( Kind of weird behavior  Created another application of ASP CORE MVC it posting form on copy button to controller

Comment: For the first issue, it's posting both values but model binding is not working because they both have the same index. For the second issue, it's submitting because the type attribute for the copy button is not specified as button, the default is submit.